# JPanel inside of JScrollPane inside of GridBagLayout doesn't scroll properly

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` inside of a `JScrollPane` inside of a `GridBagLayout`
that is not scrolling properly.  What should happen is that every time the
xxx button is pressed, a new line is added inside of the scrolling pane.
What actually happens is that if xxx is pressed, say 10 times, only the
first seven lines show up and the rest can't be scrolled to.  Can anyone
suggest changes to the source code below that will make scrolling behave
properly?  I have spent hours on this with no success, trying strategies all
over the Web.

Notes:

1. The text is split in `paintComponent` because `drawString` does
   not handle end-of-line characters.
2. The `JPanel` inside of `JScrollPane` inside of `GridBagLayout` configuration is a necessary part of a much larger
   piece of software with the same problem, so I have kept it here.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawingGUI();
    }

    private static class ScrollingPane extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        String text;

        public ScrollingPane() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
            text = "";
        }

        public void SetText(String text_x) {text = text + System.lineSeparator() + text_x;}

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            int y = -fm.getHeight();
            for (String text : text.split("\n"))
                g.drawString(text,  0,  y += fm.getHeight());
        }
    }

    static class DrawingGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        JPanel jp;
        JScrollPane js;
        ScrollingPane sp;

        int LineNum;

        DrawingGUI() {
            LineNum = 0;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("xxx");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            frame.setSize(800,800);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JButton button = new JButton("xxx");
            button.setActionCommand("add_text");
            button.addActionListener(this);
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            pane.add(button, c);

            jp = new JPanel();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.ipadx = 600;
            c.ipady = 450;
            pane.add(jp, c);

            sp = new ScrollingPane();

            js = new JScrollPane(sp);
            js.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            c.ipady = 50;
            pane.add(js, c);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("add_text".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                LineNum++;
                sp.SetText("LineNum = " + LineNum);
                sp.revalidate();
                sp.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Comment: ...............hello?

Comment: Thanks.  ScrollingPane2 was just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're short circuiting the ability of your ScrollingPane JPanel from correctly sizing itself with this line:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
```

This will fix the size of the ScrollingPane JPanel. I see that you have several possible solutions:

1. Difficult: override getPreferredSize() for the ScrollingPane JPanel, and calculate the appropriate preferred size based on the size of the text it holds and draws using FontMetrics.
2. Easier: Don't add text as you're doing, but rather have ScrollingPane use a GridLayout(0, 1) (one column, variable number of rows), and add JLabels to the ScrollingPane when new text is needed to be added. Then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on it.
3. Easier still: Don't use a ScrollingPane JPanel but rather a JTextArea, that **looks** like a JPanel and that can't be edited. Add that to the JScrollPane, and again, do not restrict its size
4. Easiest: Just use a JList as that's the functionality you are using here.

For instance, either of these would work and would look similar:

```
private static class ScrollingPane2 extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, 20);

    public ScrollingPane2() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setBackground(null);
    }

    public void SetText(String text_x) {
        textArea.append(text_x + "\n");
    }
}

private static class ScrollingPane3 extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> jList = new JList<>(listModel);

    public ScrollingPane3() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(jList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jList.setBackground(null);
    }

    public void SetText(String text_x) {
        listModel.addElement(text_x);
    }
}
```